# Typecasting dynamic object to class type passed in parameter in C#

Tags: c#, casting, json.net, json-deserialization, dynamicobject

I am trying to typecast object inside dynamic object to a type which is passed as a parameter. I searched but couldn't find any specific solution to the issue.

Firstly the structure of the class is as under:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
        public class Resultset
        {
            [DataMember]
            public DataTable dt { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string status { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string res { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public object retClass { get; set; }

            public Resultset()
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                status = string.Empty;
                res = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

The retClass object in Resultset holds any dynamic classtype structure.
Now the below method typecasts the API call result in above class to Resultset class at client's end:

```
public string sanitizeData(string apiResponse, Type classType)
{
    Resultset rs = new Resultset();
    dynamic dSerializedData = null;
    try
    {
        Convert.ChangeType(rs.retClass, classType);
        dSerializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(apiResponse);
        rs.retClass = Convert.ChangeType(dSerializedData.retClass.ToObject<typeof(classType)>(), classType);

        rs.res = dSerializedData.res;
        rs.status = dSerializedData.status;
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rs);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

The api response is getting deserialized to dynamic type easily. But Since the retClass can be of anyClass type, I have to pass the type as a parameter.
Exception arises at

```
rs.retClass = Convert.ChangeType(dSerializedData.retClass.ToObject<typeof(classType)>(), classType);
```

when I use the `ToObject<typeof(classType)>()` method, here I am using the variable as a type which is not permitted.
The above code works fine when `classType` is replaced with the name of the class. But since `retClass` object itself is dynamic, I need a generic solution to the issue.

Please help me with this specific scenario.

Comment: You need to get `ToObject<>` `MethodInfo` and then use `MakeGenericMethod` and call it

Comment: On another note, you **do not** want to use the **Type of the Type**

Comment: Passing only ```classType``` is also not working

Comment: 98 times out of 100, using `dynamic` is solving a problem by creating 2 more problems. Is there a reason you really need this?

Comment: This will help generalize my code, else I have to right all this with every API call

Comment: can you give a sample apiresponse?

Comment: I have share the structure of the class ```Resultset``` above, API response is in json wrt the structure. Only the ```retClass``` structure part will be different depending upon the call.